# You need 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu .This PC has 8.1 GB

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Windows 10 on my PC with Hardware RAID, and want to install Ubuntu as dual boot. I have 100 GB of unallocated space to install Ubuntu, but after asking for the WiFi connection, it shows this message: "You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has 8.1 GB” and gives the option to Quit.

I have searched for its answer on Google but did not find any solution.

I have tried to install both Ubuntu 16.04 then Ubuntu 18.04; both show the same message "You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has 8.1 GB" before installation, then the Quit option.

Comment: with a RAID controller, why not just attach another disk? dual boot might require a GPT partition - while the question does not even feature any `fdisk` or `gparted` information (therefore it is rather abstract).

Comment: Please run `fdisk -l && cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1` then click [edit] and add your findings to your original question. Please do not click Add Comment; use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: See 1137929 for the location of the code doing the size check.  You are probably close enough to 8.6 to change to your 8.1 and have everything work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my new Dell Latitude 7400, i tried installing from scratch with an empty disk with the same issue. It turn out that in the bios configuration, the device type was Raid. Chaning it to AHCI fixed the problem.